# what's meaning of f in "js 2f\n\t"?

Tags: gcc, assembly, linux-kernel, inline-assembly

the codes:

```
extern inline int strncmp(const char * cs, const char * ct, int count)
{
register int __res;
__asm__("cld\n"
"1:\tdecl %3\n\t"
"js 2f\n\t"
"lodsb\n\t"
"scasb\n\t"
"jne 3f\n\t"
"testb %%al, %%al\n\t"
"jne 1b\n"
"2:\txorl %%eax,%%eax\n\t"
"jmp 4f\n"
"3:\tmovl $1,%%eax\n\t"
"j1 4f\n\t"
"negl %%eax\n"
"4:"
:"=a" (__res):"D" (cs), "S" (ct), "c" (count):"si","di","cx");
return __res;
}
```

I don't understand the **f** in "**js 2f\n\t**" and the **b** in "**jne 1b\n**", How to 
understand this ? which book I should look? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this context `f` means forward and `b` means backward. So `js 2f` means *jump forward to label 2, if sign set*.

You'll want to look into `gcc inline  assembly`. I can't seem to find any reference online to include this bit, but I know you can find it in [Professional Assembly Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764579010).

Why can't we use named labels ? To quote from the book:

> If you have another asm section in your C code, you cannot use the
>   same labels again, or an error message will result due to duplicate
>   use of labels.

So what can we do ?

> The solution is to **use local labels**. Both conditional and
>   unconditional branches allow you to specify a number as a label, along
>   with a directional flag to indicate which way the processor should
>   look for the numerical label. The first occurrence of the label found
>   will be taken.

About modifiers:

> Use the f modifier to indicate the label is forward from the jump
>   instruction. To move backward, you must use the b modifier.

Comment: Does this imply that the same label can appear multiple times within the same block?

Comment: @NPE No, this means you can define a label in one block without worrying about other blocks in the same translation unit.